# Retrieve the name of a button created with innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to retrieve the name of a button created using innerHtml. My problem is really simple to understand, and sure enough, to solve. Thanks in advance!

this is my code, adding a column to a dynamic table:

```
    colonne1.innerHTML = '<td align="center"><input id=' + 
    button_id_is_id_plat+ ' type="button" name='+title+' value="Supprimer" 
    onclick="DeletePlat('+button_id_is_id_plat+')"></td>';
```

the name which contains the variable title, is what i'm looking to retrieve in my DeletePlat function. Here is what I've tried but with no positive results:

```
var my_array=document.getElementById("plat_action"); //the id of the dynamic table

var longueur = arrayLignes.length;

while(i<longueur)
{
  //I retrieve the cell which contains a string
  var cellule = my_array.rows[i].cells[0];
  //I retrieve the cell which contains the button that I've created with innerHTML
  var cellule2 = my_array.rows[i].cells[1];
  //Here, I want to retrieve the name of the button embedded into my "cellule2" variable
   if (cellule.innerText.toString()==cellule2.innerText.toString())
   {
      //treatment...
   }
}
```

I've also tried cellule2.name.toString(), but, it seems that it ain't the solution too.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: You know the name, namely title. Just incldue it already as the second parameter to DeletePlat(),like you do with the `button_id_is_id_plat` ? The next question would be then why you also need the name when you already have the id. :)

Comment: This is a bad approach, but other than that it looks like you're trying to solve a problem you shouldn't have in the first place. Take a step back and tell us what the actual goal is (I assume it's running some function for one table row, and needing the row data inside the function)

Comment: I agree with @ChrisG, this seems like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You shouldn't have to lookup what the name of a button is when you execute a function that is already bound to the button. 1. You already have access to the button itself when you execute the callback 2. the setup seems very weird. What is the end goal here? There is likely no need to search for the name in the table at all.

Comment: innerHTML creates a complete and valid dom structure, so the button is a child element of the table column.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I should have put that variable as a second parameter into the onclik function. However, when I do that, I get an exception that tells me that my second variable is undefined. I tried this:
onclick="DeletePlat('+button_id_is_id_plat+',+'my_second_var+')"

Comment: Here's how you can do this without composing HTML strings or searching for elements: https://jsfiddle.net/khrismuc/g6bpsy9m/

Comment: Updated the fiddle to use actual data and show how to remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here an example of what you could do in order to retrieve the name from a button `html` element:

```js
let buttonElement = document.getElementById("button");
let name = buttonElement.getAttribute('name');
console.log(name)
```

```html
<button name="buttonname" type="submit" value="HTML" id="button">HTML</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

To rerieve the name of a button no need to call toString() function : just use the .name attribute of your DOM element :

```js
console.log(document.getElementById("button").name);
```

```html
<div id="div">
  <button id="button" name="nameOfButton">Button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The `toString()` is redundant, yes, but it's trying to find the correct element, not to determine what the name of it is.